# Copying contents from iframe into input

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

Hi new to coding and scripting, here is what I have:

```
<html>
<body>

<p align="left"><iframe id="aa" style="HEIGHT: 25px; WIDTH: 227px"src="http://www.html-assets.com/assets/html-building-blocks/php-display-user-ip-address.php" frameborder="0" width="600" name="aa" scrolling="no"></iframe></p>



</br><input type="text" id="ee">

<input type="checkbox" name="dd" value=" onclick="myFunction()"><em>Check the box to     copy the IP Address above</em>

<script>
myFunction() {


var x = document.getElementById("aa");
var y =(x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);

if(dd.oncheck==true){
f.ee.value = y;
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do is have something where the page lists out the IP Address of an end-user. I want the user to have the ability to copy this address into an input field that can be added to a form that can be submitted.

How would I script this? At this point, the object in my iframe is outside my domain; is this impossible to call because of the same origin policy? I am planning on creating this using a .php within our own domain; I will adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: *sidenote:* use lower-case CSS . Plus, which size do you want to be iframe's width, 227 or 600 ? Also, you shouldn't wrap `iframe` with `p`

Comment: also, your JS function syntax is incorrect. missing `function` keyword

Comment: I am just using the iframe to hold the source that I am referring to because this script is only in a mockup stage, the size isn't important for now; I still need to create a .php with the IP Address values and possibly a port checker. Where do I put the "function" keyword? I just started learning this stuff last week.

Comment: @AlmightyWhy you are doing **great** for a beginner! Don't worry about what the other's say. :)

Comment: instead of `myFunction() {` , use `function myFunction() {` as it is a JavaScript function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to use a `.php` file for this.

Once you have created your php file, then insert this code:

```
<?php
$userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
<input type="text" value="" id="textbox1"/>
<input type="button" value="Click me" onClick="document.getElementById('textbox1').value = '<?php echo $userip;?>' "/>
```

The user's ip will be saved in the variable `$userip`. Then, when the button is pressed, the textbox `textbox1` will be filled with the user's ip address.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, then when I refer to the variable in the html code I would set it up in a div and then code the Javascript so that when the button is clicked the value of the input field would match the contents of the div which would be the variable; is this correct? Thank you

Comment: So on button click the textbox should be filled with the ip address? Hang on, I will just edit my code...

Comment: There, it is edited now according to your needs. Let me know of anything else I can help you with!